# How to make the first part of the textlines unique and concatenate the second part in batch?

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, if-statement

I have following lines in my formatliste_droid.txt:

```
Z:\15_Testdateien\jhove_Script_fuer_MIX-Verzeichnisse\testfiles\1002779294_sf_droid_no_match.pdf$fmt/95
Z:\15_Testdateien\jhove_Script_fuer_MIX-Verzeichnisse\testfiles\1002779294_sf_droid_no_match.pdf$fmt/477
Z:\15_Testdateien\jhove_Script_fuer_MIX-Verzeichnisse\testfiles\1002779294_sf_droid_no_match.pdf$fmt/354
```

The first part before $ is repeated and needs to be unique. The second part after  $ is always different. 
So what I need is the transformation to one unique path concatenated with all second parts of the line after $

```
Z:\15_Testdateien\jhove_Script_fuer_MIX-Verzeichnisse\testfiles\1002779294_sf_droid_no_match.pdf$fmt/95$fmt/477$fmt/354
```

---

```
   @echo off
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    set "prevLine="
    for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=$" %%a in (formatliste_droid.txt) do (
       if "%%a" neq "!prevLine!" (
          echo %%a$%%b>>_formatliste_droid.txt
          set "prevLine=%%a"
       )

    )
```

With this code I can make unique line, but parts of the line after $ are lost except from the first line. Is there a way to concatenate them all with unique path? I always need to check if there are identical pathes and then make them unique concatenating with all results after $

Comment: What is stopping you from using an `ELSE` to do something when they are equal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you are really missing is using some `ELSE` logic to do something when it is equal and not equal.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "prevLine="
set "newLine="
(for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=$" %%a in (formatliste_droid.txt) do (
    if "%%a"=="!prevLine!" (
        set "newline=!newline!$%%b"
    ) ELSE (
        IF DEFINED newline echo !newline!
        set "newline=%%a$%%b"
    )
    set "prevline=%%a"
)
echo !newline!
)>_formatliste_droid.txt
```